# XLNet or BERT Chinese for HuggingFace AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM Training

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I want to use the pre-trained XLNet (`xlnet-base-cased`, which the model type is *Text Generation*) or BERT Chinese (`bert-base-chinese`, which the model type is *Fill Mask*) for Sequence to Sequence Language Model (`Seq2SeqLM`) training.

I can use `facebook/bart-large` (which the model type is *Feature Extraction*) for constructing the `Seq2SeqLM`, but not the 2 pretrained models mentioned above. Here is my code below:

**Load Dataset**

```
from datasets import load_dataset
yuezh = load_dataset("my-custom-dataset")
```

**Sample data from the dataset** `my-custom-dataset`

```
{"translation": {"yue": "又睇", "zh": "再看"}}
{"translation": {"yue": "初頭", "zh": "開始的時候"}}
```

**Create Test Split**

```
yuezh = yuezh["train"].train_test_split(test_size=0.2)
print(yuezh)
```

Output:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 4246
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 1062
    })
})
```

**Tokenizer**

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
checkpoint = 'bert-base-chinese'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
```

**Pre-process Function**

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
    inputs = [prefix + example[source_lang] for example in examples["translation"]]
    targets = [example[target_lang] for example in examples["translation"]]
    model_inputs = tokenizer(inputs, text_target=targets, max_length=128, truncation=True)
    return model_inputs
```

**Parameters**

```
source_lang = "yue"
target_lang = "zh"
prefix = "Translate this: "
tokenized_yuezh = yuezh.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
tokenized_yuezh = tokenized_yuezh.remove_columns(yuezh["train"].column_names)
print(tokenized_yuezh)
```

Output:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask', 'labels'],
        num_rows: 4246
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask', 'labels'],
        num_rows: 1062
    })
})
```

**Evaluate Performance**

```
# Use ScareBLEU to evaluate the performance
import evaluate
metric = evaluate.load("sacrebleu")
```

**Data Collator**

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq
data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=checkpoint)
```

**Supporting Functions**

```
import numpy as np

def postprocess_text(preds, labels):
    preds = [pred.strip() for pred in preds]
    labels = [[label.strip()] for label in labels]

    return preds, labels


def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)

    result = metric.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels)
    result = {"bleu": result["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds]
    result["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    result = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result
```

**Training**

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
training_args = CustomSeq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="my-output-dir",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    fp16=True,
    push_to_hub=False, # Don't push to Hub yet
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_yuezh["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_yuezh["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

It results in the following errors:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 
'transformers.models.bert.configuration_bert.BertConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: 
AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.
Model type should be one of BartConfig, BigBirdPegasusConfig, BlenderbotConfig, 
BlenderbotSmallConfig, EncoderDecoderConfig, FSMTConfig, LEDConfig, LongT5Config, 
M2M100Config, MarianConfig, MBartConfig, MT5Config, MvpConfig, PegasusConfig, PegasusXConfig,
PLBartConfig, ProphetNetConfig, SwitchTransformersConfig, T5Config, XLMProphetNetConfig.
```

The `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` does not support XLNet or BERT. What should I do to make the Sequence-to-Sequence training work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xlnet-base-cased](https://huggingface.co/xlnet-base-cased) [bert-base-chinese](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-chinese) can not be loaded directly with [AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM) because it expects a model that can perform seq2seq tasks.

But you can leverage these checkpoints for a seq2seq model thanks to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12461) and the [EncoderDecoderModel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12461) class:

```py
from transformers import EncoderDecoderModel, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
# This will use the weights of bert-base-chinese for the encoder and the decoder
model = EncoderDecoderModel.from_encoder_decoder_pretrained("bert-base-chinese", "bert-base-chinese")
model.config.decoder_start_token_id = tokenizer.cls_token_id

# You can later load it as AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM 
#model.save_pretrained("my_seq2seqbert")
#model1 = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("my_seq2seqbert")
```

I haven't tested it, but it seems XLNet can not be used as a decoder according to this [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8778#issuecomment-733952780). In this case, you can try to use a decoder like gpt with cross-attention:

```py
model = EncoderDecoderModel.from_encoder_decoder_pretrained("xlnet-base-cased", "gpt2")
#model.save_pretrained("my_seq2seqxlnet-base-cased")
#model1 = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("my_seq2seqxlnet-base-cased")
```

Comment: For 2 approaches above, I encountered error: `ValueError: Make sure to set the decoder_start_token_id attribute of the model's 
configuration.`. What value should I use in the property `decoder_start_token_id`?

Comment: Solved. I added `model.config.decoder_start_token_id = tokenizer.cls_token_id`

Comment: That is fine @Raptor.