# AttributeError: 'Seq2SeqTrainer' object has no attribute 'push_in_progress'

Tags: python, huggingface

I'm using HuggingFace's `Seq2SeqTrainer` and I successfully trained a model. When I try to execute (where trainer is an instance of `Seq2SeqTrainer`):

```
trainer.push_to_hub()
```

It returns error:

> AttributeError: 'Seq2SeqTrainer' object has no attribute 'push_in_progress'

Trainer Code:

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
trainer.train()
trainer.push_to_hub()
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Other codes can be found in my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945735/xlnet-or-bert-chinese-for-huggingface-automodelforseq2seqlm-training).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I have to add the following line before the `push_to_hub()` line:

```
model.push_in_progress = None
```

Using `huggingface_hub` version 0.12.0